# Method of lines for a mixed PDE

Tags: pde, matlab, method-of-lines

I am trying to solve the following PDE using the method of lines to discretize space, and then solve it as system of ODEs at each point in space using ODE15s:

[image]

subject to

[image]

and initial condition $w(z,t=0) = 0$.

I know this must be possible because the paper I'm reading has done this, but I cannot find how to reproduce it. She used a finite difference method for discretising space, but I am left with the issue that space must be discretised under the time derivative also and I don't know how to use ODE15s in that situation. Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. Can you type your equations instead of using images? Particularly, because it seems to be a typo in your last boundary condition

Comment: If you introduce $u=\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$, then this is just the heat equation for $u$.

Comment: I don't know how the author's of the paper did it, but you could discretize the space derivative in the LHS then pass it to `ode15s` as a mass matrix. I can't imagine that would be very efficieint though.

Comment: Can you give a link to the paper? It seems really strange that the problem wasn't written as the heat equation in the first place.